# What is the Prism equivalent of DispatcherHelper?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, mvvm-light

I am rewriting a code base from MVVMLight to Prism. I have an interface IDispatchOnUIThread that I am implementing in iOS.

What is the equivalent of MVVMLight's DispatchHelper in Prism ?

```
using MyApp.Model;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Threading;
using System;

namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class DispatchOnUIThread : IDispatchOnUIThread
    {
        public void Invoke(Action action)
        {
            DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(action);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such thing in the `Prism` lib. Maybe cause `Xamarin.Forms` offers it out of the box: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

So you could go:

```
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class DispatchOnUIThread : IDispatchOnUIThread
    {
        public void Invoke(Action action)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(action);
        }
    }
}
```